# Bootstrap and asymmetric CI

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to create confidence interval for a set of data **not** randomly distributed and very skewed at right. Surfing, I discovered a pretty rude method that consists in using the 97.5% percentile (of my data) for the upperbound CL and 2.5% percentile for your lower CL.
Unfortunately, I need a more sophisticated way!

Then I discovered the **bootstrap**, precisley the MATLAB bootci function, but I'm having hard time to undestand how to used it properly.

Let's say that `M` is my matrix containing my data (19x100), and let's say that:

```
Mean = mean(M,2);
StdDev = sqrt(var(M'))';
```

How can I compute the **asymmetrical** CI for every row of the `Mean` vector using bootci?

*Note: earlier, I was computing the CI in this **very wrong** way: `Mean +/- 2 * StdDev`, shame on me!*

Comment: CI: asymmetrical how? I guess you have to make a choice, I doubt Matlab can make that choice for you, right?

Comment: @francesco I thought that bootstrap in Matlab can calibrate the two CI. I found the `bootstrap` advice in the same place of 97.5%-2.5% advice. So I thought that bootstrap somehow can make it work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a `100x19` data set. Each column has a different distribution. We'll choose the log normal distribution, so that they skew to the right.

```
means  = repmat(log(1:19), 100, 1);
stdevs = ones(100, 19);
X = lognrnd(means, stdevs);
```

Notice that each *column* is from the same distribution, and the *rows* are separate observations. Most functions in MATLAB operate on the rows by default, so it's always preferable to keep your data this way around.

You can compute bootstrap confidence intervals for the mean using the `bootci` function.

```
ci = bootci(1000, @mean, X);
```

This does 1000 resamplings of your data, calculates the mean for each resampling and then takes the 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles. To show that it's an asymmetric confidence interval about the mean, we can plot the mean and the confidence intervals for each column

```
plot(mean(X), 'r')
hold on
plot(ci')
```

[image]